# Git operations that changes file system doesn't trigger FileWatcher

Tags: c#, git, file-watcher

I have an interesting problem, my system is a winforms, but also console app, that watchers for file changes in a folder.

Everything works great, but if that folder is a local git repo and there are operations that would change the files, the file watcher is not fired!

ex:

```
git restore 1.txt
```

The above removes the change from the git working tree and will not trigger the filewatcher.

Comment: [MCVE] is missing... 99% you are listening in a wrong place or for wrong changes.

Comment: That might involve a file rename from %TEMP% into the directory. You could use Process Monitor to work out exactly what file operations are performed. Or maybe just watch `.git/index`